# New test accounts in paypal sandbox getting Account is restricted error

Tags: paypal

I've just moved over to the new Sandbox site for paypal. I was unable to get any of my original test accounts to import for some reason so I just created a bunch of new accounts which I can see in the Sandbox Test Accounts screen.

I've migrated my application over to the new test accounts and upon performing a chained payment I'm getting errors back saying that the Accounts are restricted.

I'm aware this means that an account has not yet been setup but I'm pretty sure they're sitting there looking at me.

Next thought was have the url's changed? Doccos I've found on the new site point to the same urls so now I'm confused.

Could this be a synch thing that takes time for accounts to be recognised??

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you move any information to the new accounts that would be proprietary to the original accounts, like access codes or account numbers?

Comment: i created these accounts from fresh using they're create account form. My site is using the default ***-facilitor@gmail.com account and these credentials are fresh as well.